# PyQt4 menubar doesn't appear in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, qt4, pyqt4

I am using python with Pyqt4 for building app on Ubuntu and seems I have trouble with menubar that doesn't show up, thanks for any help. here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):              
    def __init__(self):
         super(Example, self).__init__()        
         self.initUI()        
    def initUI(self):                      
         exitAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)        
         exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
         exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
         exitAction.triggered.connect(QtGui.qApp.quit)
         self.statusBar()
         menubar = self.menuBar()
         fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
         fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)        
         self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
         self.setWindowTitle('Menubar')    
         self.show()       
def main():    
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Excuse me if the indentation wouldn't be correct but I think it is.

Comment: There's no _programming_ reason why this shouldn't work. It must be an issue with your setup.

Comment: thanks both of you, I am sure it works on windows but do you have any idea why it doesn't work on Ubuntu? and only Menu Bar doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think ubuntu is the issue, but the desktop environment you use. Do you use gnome3, gnome, unity, kde, xface or some other?

Comment: @jesy2013. It works for me on Linux. Try creating a menubar in Qt Designer and preview it with some other styles to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks i've done all those. but the thing I didn't know was the menu on linux appear outside the window at the corner lol

Comment: @jesy2013. Not sure I understand what you mean. Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: @ekhumoro. you know that in ubuntu the menu of every browser,application and others showed up in the right corner of the screen opposite the (e.g. clock,wireless,battery...).

Comment: @jesy2013. No - I've never really used ubuntu. Is this one of the infamous "improvements" introduced with gnome3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ubuntu menubar is outside the application . You can find it in global menu

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
menuBar = self.menuBar()
menuBar.setNativeMenuBar(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code. First you should run your code and maximize your GUI(Graphical User Interface) and you can see that your code run fine and you can understand what actually happen in Ubuntu. Actually Ubuntu always show the menu bar (also your GUI) at the top of the screen no matter what the size of your application.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there is your menu. You can just full screen your application and it would be on the top of the window if you hover your mouse on that.

This is Ubuntu mode of visualisation, exactly like your browser that if you hover your mouse over the menu bar, you can see it!

Comment: Hey, sorry for voting your answer down, and I don't know if you are correct or not, but I don't think that you have fully understood the question. For whatever reason, s/he isn't getting a menubar to show up in their app, and they are wondering what they might need to do to fix it. You've just said "but it should be there", which is simply an assertion.

Comment: Thanks for voting BTW. S/he said menubar is not showing up. I faced the same thing, but actually there is a menubar, which you cannot see until you put your mouse over it, and then it shows up. If you are using ubuntu, you can try it with Chromium browser, when your mouse is in the middle of the screen, there is a title on top of the chromium, but when you move your mouse on that, the menu bar appears. So, there is a menu bar over there.